# ERROR: invalid regular expression: invalid character range in postgresql

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

Trying to insert right row but can't because it violates check constraint

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.authors
(
    au_id character varying(11) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    au_lname character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    au_fname character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    phone character(12) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL DEFAULT 'UNKNOWN'::bpchar,
    address character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    city character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    state character(2) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    zip character(5) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    contract bit(1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT authors_au_id_primary_key PRIMARY KEY (au_id),
    CONSTRAINT authors_au_zip_check CHECK (zip ~ similar_to_escape('[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-
9][0-9]'::text)),
    CONSTRAINT authors_au_id_check CHECK (au_id::text ~ similar_to_escape('[0-9][0-9][0-9][-][0-9][0-9][-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'::text))
)
```

Insert:

```
INSERT into authors VALUES('409-56-7008', 'Bennet', 'Abraham', '415 658-9932',  '6223 Bateman St.', 'Berkeley', 'CA', '94705', 1::bit);
```

Error:
ERROR:  invalid regular expression: invalid character range

SQL state: 2201B

Comment: Which column/value combination is causing the error? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, it looks as if one of constraints is wrongly set (because of CRLF in the middle of regular expression):

```
CONSTRAINT authors_au_zip_check CHECK (zip ~ similar_to_escape('[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-
9][0-9]'::text)),
```

If it were a single-line:

```
CONSTRAINT authors_au_zip_check CHECK (zip ~ similar_to_escape('[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'::text)),
```

then code - (`insert` included) - works. Have a look at the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HNGgq16e).

Answer (score 0):

There is practically no reason to be messing with ranges. You can use the [digit meta escape](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-ESCAPE-SEQUENCES) with a [fixed repetition quantifier](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-MATCHING-RULES):

```
CONSTRAINT authors_au_zip_check CHECK (zip ~ similar_to_escape('\d{5}'::text)),
CONSTRAINT authors_au_id_check CHECK (au_id::text ~ similar_to_escape('\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}'::text))
```